# LinkedIn API: Creating UGC Image Post for Organization 500 response

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm attempting to post images to organization linkedin pages. I'm working off of this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api

So far I have the following working:

- shareMediaCategory type "ARTICLE" shared to a person
- shareMediaCategory type "ARTICLE" shared to an organization
- shareMediaCategory type "IMAGE" shared to a person

When I attempt to post with shareMediaCategory type "IMAGE" to an organization, I get the following error response:

```
{
    "message": "Internal Server Error",
    "status": 500
}
```

Here is the url:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts
```

The Headers (I have tried with and without all these headers):

```
Authorization:Bearer REDACTED
Content-Type:application/json
X-Restli-Protocol-Version:2.0.0
x-li-format:json
```

And the body:

```
{
   "author":"urn:li:organization:2414183",
   "lifecycleState":"PUBLISHED",
   "specificContent":{
      "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent":{
         "shareCommentary":{
            "text":"Hello"
         },
         "shareMediaCategory":"IMAGE",
         "media":[
            {
               "status": "READY",
               "description":{
                  "text":"Here is the description"
               },
               "media":"urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C4E22AQFdCtnVOTxQCQ",
               "title":{
                  "text":"This is the title"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "visibility":{
      "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility":"PUBLIC"
   }
}
```

The organization id is a LinkedIn test org ID: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/organizations/development-testing

I can post articles to that ID, but images 500.

I've tested that the image has been uploaded successfully.